# how to use htacces to restrict access to all files in a folder and it's subfolders and redirect to main?

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, elgg

So I'm on a 15-day trial of my (already paid) webhosting and they seem very good, at least they did until I got my FTP.

I have a php script that needs a folder outside of the root directory

---

**Example:**

website root:

`/users/websites/public_html/` <- folder which users / browsers have access to

The script needs a folder here:

`/users/websites/` <- above the root

for example `/users/websites/sensetive_data/` <- browsers cannot acces this

---

but that's impossible on my web-host `"because it's a shared hosting"` <- their answer. And they can't change the root path.

So I cannot create any directories or files above `/users/websites/public_html/`

So, well, to no cancel my trial immediately, maybe I will try to do it in another way, I want to use htacces to restrict acces to a directory, and all the files in it and it's subdirectories,

So I can move the 'sensetive_data' folder to `/users/websites/public_html/sensetive_data`

I want it to redirect to the main page (so when accessing /users/websites/public_html/sensetive_data/* [http://example.com/sensetive_data/*] it will go to /users/websites/public_html/ [http://example.com/],

so even if the user knows the exact url, he/she will be redirected. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a redirect for a folder, say `/users/websites/sensitive_data/`

create a file in that folder called `.htaccess` and add the following (and specify the url to redirect to)

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 http://mysite.net/
```

Answer (score 1):

In `/users/websites/sensetive_data/.htaccess` write:

```
Deny From All
```

For your whatever PHP script you need to change it yourself.